# content-security-policy-report-only report-uri with fully qualified absolute URL

Tags: url, uri, content-security-policy

when using content-security-policy-report-only report-uri, is it possible to have a fully-qualified absolute URL for the 'report-uri' value?  All examples I see are relative values that go back to the application itself.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can place a full URL in the report-uri directive.

I run an external reporting service at https://report-uri.com for doing exactly this!